# Is context passed by reference

Tags: entity-framework

Hi I found a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/309753/Repository-Pattern-with-Entity-Framework-4-1-and-C?msg=4516612#xx4516612xx) that contains this code.

```
var context=new ApplicationContext();
var userRepo=new Repository<User>(context);
var user =new User()
                    {
                      Username = "TestName"
                    };
userRepo.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

`userRepo` has a private variable called `_context` so does calling `context.SaveChanges()` mean that context was passed by reference in the Repository constructor? Why are we not making `_context` public and then calling `userRepo._context.SaveChanges()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is passed by reference. `ApplicationContext` is a `class` and every class variable in C# is passed by reference into a method.

Calling `context.SaveChanges` makes it clearer that a whole unit of work is committed that could span several repositories, not only one.

For example you could create a second repository `var roleRepo=new Repository<Role>(context);` and do some operations like adding a new `Role`. `context.SaveChanges` will commit all changes and insert the added user and the added role in a single transaction. Using `userRepo._context.SaveChanges()` (which is technically possible with a public `_context` and would do exactly the same) might lead to the wrong idea that only changes done in the user repository are saved. But in fact all changes done with any repository that got the `context` passed are saved.